# Node.js installation was successful but, while running a test file it is showing an error

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is the error while I'm running from Node.js Command prompt:
[image: This is the error while I'm running from Node.js Command prompt]

This is the error while I'm running from power shell or CMD:
[image: This is the error while I'm running from power shell or CMD]

This is the code file:
[image: This is the code file]

This is the error file from power shell while command - "node myfirst.js":
[image: This is the error file from power shell while command - "node myfirst.js"]

Code:

```
var http = require('https');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
res.end('Hello World!');
}).listen(8080);
```

Error:

```
asd.js : The term 'asd.js' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, 
or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and 
try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ asd.js
+ ~~~~~~
+ Category Info          : ObjectNotFound: (asd.js:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: node `yourmainfile.js`

Answer (score 0):

To run your node.js script, type `node <filename>`, in your case: `node ast.js`.

The error https://i.stack.imgur.com/llqlm.png indicates that there's a port conflict, another process already uses 8080 port.

To fix it, kill the process who uses 8080 port, or just use another port:

```js
var http = require('https');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
res.end('Hello World!');
}).listen(9999); // another port
```